# How to use aggregation in mongodb with Java to find occurence of a field multiple times?

Tags: java, mongodb

I have a collection in mongodb - "text_failed" which has all the numbers on which I failed to send an SMS, the time they failed and some other information.

A document in this collection looks like this:

```
{
    _id(ObjectId): xxxxxx2af8....
    failTime(String): 2015-05-15 01:15:48
    telNum(String): 95634xxxxx
    //some other information    
}
```

I need to fetch the top 500 numbers which failed the most in a month's duration. A number can occur any number of time during this month.(Eg: a number failed 143 times, other 46 etc.)

The problem I have is that during this duration the numbers failed crossed 7M. It's difficult to process this much information using the following code which doesn't use aggregation:

```
    DBCollection collection = mongoDB.getCollection("text_failed");
    BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
    query.put("failTime", new BasicDBObject("$gt", "2015-05-15 00:00:00").append("$lt", "2015-06-15 00:00:00"));
    BasicDBObject field = new BasicDBObject();
    field.put("telNum", 1);

    DBCursor cursor = collection.find(query, field);
    HashMap<String, Integer> hm = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    //int count = 1;
    System.out.println(cursor);
    while(cursor.hasNext()) {

        //System.out.println(count);
        //count++;
        DBObject object = cursor.next();

        if(hm.containsKey(object.get("telNum").toString())) {
            hm.put(object.get("telNum").toString(), hm.get(object.get("telNum").toString()) + 1);
        } 
        else {
            hm.put(object.get("telNum").toString(), 1);
        }

    }
```

This fetches 7M+ documents for me. I need only the top 500 numbers. The result should look something like this:

```
{
    telNum: xxxxx54654 //the number which failed
    count: 129 //number of times it failed    
}
```

I used aggregation myself but didn't get the desired results. Can this be accomplished by aggregation? Or is there any other way more efficient in which I can do this?

Comment: is the `failTime` field a string or Date object in MongoDB?

Comment: failTime and telNum, both are String.

Comment: Can you post the aggregation query which you tried which you are telling is not working ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following aggregation pipeline:

```
db.getCollection("text_failed").aggregate([
    {
        "$match": {
            "failTime": { "$gt": "2015-05-01 00:00:00", "$lt": "2015-06-01 00:00:00" }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$telNum",
            "count": { "$sum": 1 }                
        }
    },
    {
        "$sort": { "count": -1 }
    },
    {
        "$limit": 500
    }
])
```

Comment: OP's is asking for TOP 500 documents which are sorted based on the count obtained not on the failTime.

Comment: `failTime` was `String`  and is not possible to compare to two string , either convert `failTime` `String` to `ISODate`.

Comment: There is NO index created on the "count" field, at worst case lets assume that we have 7M documets comes out of the group output, so there will be lot of performance issues in sorting all those 7M documets based on "count" field rite ?

Comment: Of course there's bound to be performance issues because you can't create an index on a created field from the aggregation pipeline. Map-Reduce is another option but that suffers the same fate as well though the aggregation framework is better in terms of performance. Up to the OP's call really.

Comment: @yogesh It is indeed possible to compare two strings. Probably the biggest advantage of using the MongoDB BSON Date type instead of a string is that you can only use the aggregate Date operators with BSON Date values. But if you don't need to do any aggregation of your data, using a sortable string format to represent dates is fine and often cleaner as you don't need to deal with time zone related display problems.